# jQuery $('.classname').length fails, but $.find('.classname').length works, why?

Tags: jquery, find, classname

My JavaScript module fails to find a particular DOM element with a classname using `$('.classname')` even when the element exists.

`$('.classname').length` returns 0, where as `$.find('.classname').length` returns 1.

Website contains other JavaScript modules also.

Can anyone help me to find why this is happening?

My jQuery version is 1.7.1.

To reproduce this 
1- Go to avc.com
2- Open console.
3- Paste the following code in console.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];  
var script = document.createElement("script");  
script.type = "text/javascript";  
script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";  
script.async = true;  
head.appendChild(script);
```

4- Try
    `$('.pkg').length` and `$.find('.pkg').length`.

Find the screen-shot from here https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZo7w.png

One more point, if you try this in some other websites, It works correctly.

Comment: On your page does: alert(jQuery == $) give you a value of true?

Comment: This works http://jsfiddle.net/GaSXP/

Comment: @SheikhHeera can you give it a try, I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

You may have some conflicts with your other JavaScript modules. Look into jQuery [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of
>   $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict()

Try using

```
jQuery('.classname').length
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have already used noconflict. My questions was why $('.classname').length returns 0 and the same $.find('.classname').length returns 1

Comment: Could you try replicating your problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am working on a extension which will inject JavaScript to all websites. I have noticed this happens with avc.com. Here is a screen-shot of what happens - http://i.imgur.com/4UDHz.png

To reproduce this
Go to avc.com
Open console.
Paste the following code.

'var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
script.async = true;
head.appendChild(script);' 

Then try 
$('.pkg').length

$.find('.pkg').length