# How to access elements in the same iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I want to access elements in a same iframe (they're even in same user control), but the only way I know is:

```
<div>
...
    <asp:Button CssClass="enoPlaceOrderButton enoHidden" runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" OnClick="SubmitButton_OnClick" Text="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("body").bind("checkout.onStepChanged", function (event, data) {
        if (data.currentStep == "PaymentStep") {
            var temp = jQuery("#paymentMethodsFrame").contents().find('#<%=SubmitButton.ClientID %>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</div>
```

This is in the paymentMethodsFrame.

Is there a better way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use

```
jQuery('#SubmitButton');
```

Comment: it just can not find the button with this way. Have you ever tried it?

Comment: @Vimvq1987 is it anywhere related to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890878/jquery-classname-length-fails-but-find-classname-length-works-why